# Dont work park functionality of babel-preset-env

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have class:

```
class App extends Component {

  setName = () => {
    this.props.setName('Test')
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.setName}>
        <h1>Wolcome to React</h1>
        <p>
          Test <b>HRM</b>. {this.props.user.name}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Webpack modules config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:[
          { loader: 'babel-loader' },
          { loader: 'eslint-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2",
    "stage-0",
    "react",
  ],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

When build scripts I have error:

```
  8:11  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

And the same problem with bind(transform-do-expressions), If I use `onClick={e => ::this.someAction}` construction have error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your babel config, it works fine. You're using `eslint-loader` and eslint does not understand the class properties, because they are not yet part of JavaScript and the default parser doesn't include them. You can configure eslint to use [`babel-eslint`](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint) as the parser instead. With that it works with every valid babel code.

In your eslint config add:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint"
```

More information on [Specifying Parser](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setName` function instead and bind `setName` method in the constructor like this

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
  } 

  setName(){
     this.props.setName('Test')
  };
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but babel must compile my code, this is valid for babel-preset-env and i dont understand why it doesnt work

Comment: you can add `"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]` to your .babelrc and it should work for you according to this `https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/`

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to specify stage-2 if you specify stage-0.
2. You don't have to specify stage-{x} if you specify `env` because `babel-preset-env` loads plugins only for specified environments (browsers, node).

   **.babelrc**

   ```
   {
       "presets": [
           ["env", {
               "targets": {
                   "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "> 5%"],
                   "node": true
               },
               "debug": false,
               "modules": false,
               "useBuiltIns": true
           }],
           "react"
       ]
   }
   ```
3. [From babel-preset-env repository](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#support-all-plugins-in-babel-that-are-considered-latest)

   > It won't include stage-x plugins.
4. The official [list of experimental babel plugins](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#transform-plugins-experimental)

   ```
   async-generator-functions
   async-to-module-method
   class-constructor-call (deprecated)
   class-properties
   decorators
   do-expressions
   export-extensions
   function-bind
   object-rest-spread
   ```

Finally, based on your code, you have to specify in your babel-preset-env config experimental plugin `class-properties`, you used it here

```
setName = () => {
    this.props.setName('Test')
};
```

Your config should look more or less like this

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", {
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "> 2%"]
            }
        }],
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Please bear in mind that if you would like to use also `::` syntax which is `transform-function-bind`, you have also add it to plugins.